# MVC.NET adding jQuery validator function via data annotations?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to figure out the black box behavior going on with data annotations.  I created a custom annotator and applied it to the model field.  Somewhere along the way it is creating a jQuery validator method which will be fired client side on a form input change using jQuery validation.  Is there an internal MVC.NET script which is dynamically creating these client side validators based on the attribute on the model field?

Here is the javascript created and attached using a custom C# data annotation to prevent future date.  I did not write this code, something in the MVC.NET stack did.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("futureDate", function(n) {
    var t = new Date;
    return Date.parse(n) > t ? !1 :!0
});
```

Comment: I think jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js is responsible for client side validation

Comment: correct, but what and where created this javascript method that allowed jQuery to know how to validate.  MVC.NET stack is building this client side code.

Comment: https://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/2012/01/18/custom-unobtrusive-jquery-validation-with-data-annotations-in-mvc-3/  
I think this link answers your question.

Comment: There is nothing in the MVC framework which creates that script (or any other scripts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to understand how MVC.NET convert it into client side validation, [this link](http://rachelappel.com/asp-net-mvchow-data-annotations-for-asp-net-mvc-validation-work/) should help you:

"Both client and server side validation work because of a few conventions in your project that match up data annotations, Html Helpers, rendered output. Html Helpers in views render HTML elements containing attributes that start with the pattern data-val-*. The data-val-* attributes contain error messages, regular expressions, ranges, and other validation information that originates in data annotations." Copied from the link.

Check the link. It is always good to ask youself why.